# In iOS how do I trigger a method when an MPMoviePlayerController is at a specific timecode?

Tags: ios, swift

I've implemented an MPMoviePlayerController which works perfectly. I'm looking to fire a method when the movie gets to a specific time code. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code below in Swift.

```
import MediaPlayer

class VideoPlayerController: UIViewController {
    var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("timelapse-night", ofType: "mp4") {
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            moviePlayer.contentURL = url
            moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
            moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
            self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
            moviePlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController has a property with the current time: currentPlaybackTime

You can create an NSTimer when the video begins to play -

```
NSTimer *checkVideoTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                       target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(getCurrentVideoTime)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
```

The timer will execute the method getCurrentVideoTime every second (1.0f). In that method you should put

```
if (moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime == theTimeYouWantToDoSomething)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Just realized you're in swift - you should still be able to use the currentPlaybackTime property though